# Writing to s3n: from Databricks gives "PermissionError: Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I run the following code in Data Bricks:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( [ [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2] ], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('s3n://***/***/dummy.csv', index=False)
```

Been getting this error:

> PermissionError: Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation

I have an AWS Root User account, may I know what steps must I take to enable access?

Comment: You did you setup your access? Your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: May I know what details I should include? I'm very new to Big Data/ Cloud. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536517/permissionerror-while-using-pandas-to-csv-function

Comment: For example, you haven't even provided how where do you run the code? EC2 instance, Lmabda, ECS container? Local computer?

Comment: I run it on Data Bricks Community Edition > Workspace > Create Notebook

Comment: I managed to mount from the S3 Bucket to Data Bricks by going to AWS > IAM > Users > Create User > Security Credentials > Download the Access Key and Secret Key
However, I can't write back From Data Bricks to S3 Bucket as it shows PermissionError: Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AWS credentials for your notebook.
There's a complete guide on [credentials passthrough on databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/security/credential-passthrough/iam-passthrough.html).

Notebook environments are different than your databricks account integrations (S3 mount) with AWS.

If you run these notebooks locally, you'll get similar access error unless you have set up AWS credentials via `aws configure` or environment variables.